# Why is neovim unable to locate the packer module?

Tags: neovim

I'm trying to install [packer.nvim](https://github.com/wbthomason/packer.nvim) using the quickstart guide. I cloned the repository using

```
git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/wbthomason/packer.nvim\
 ~/.local/share/nvim/site/pack/packer/start/packer.nvim
```

and created the file `~/.config/nvim/lua/plugins.lua` with these contents:

```
return require('packer').startup(function()
  -- Packer can manage itself
  use 'wbthomason/packer.nvim'
end)
```

My `~/.config/nvim/init.vim` has only the line `lua require('plugins')`.

When I run `nvim` I get the following error:

```
Error detected while processing /home/user/.config/nvim/init.vim:
line    1:
E5105: Error while calling lua chunk: /home/user/.config/nvim/lua/plugins.lua:6: module 'packer' not found:
        no field package.preload['packer']
        no file '/home/user/.config/nvim/lua/packer.lua'
        no file '/home/user/.config/nvim/lua/packer/init.lua'
        no file '/etc/xdg/xdg-i3/nvim/lua/packer.lua'
        ... (many more missing files)
```

I tried checking my `packpath` in neovim with `:set packpath?` but I'm not sure whether it's correct or not.

```
packpath=~/.config/nvim,/etc/xdg/xdg-i3/nvim,/etc/xdg/nvim,~/.local/share/nvim/site,/usr/share/i3/nvi
m/site,/usr/local/share/nvim/site,/usr/share/nvim/site,/var/lib/snapd/desktop/nvim/site,/usr/share/nvim
/runtime,/var/lib/snapd/desktop/nvim/site/after,/usr/share/nvim/site/after,/usr/local/share/nvim/site/a
fter,/usr/share/i3/nvim/site/after,~/.local/share/nvim/site/after,/etc/xdg/nvim/after,/etc/xdg/xdg-i3/n
vim/after,~/.config/nvim/after
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: https://github.com/wbthomason/packer.nvim/discussions

Comment: I take it you mean I should post my question there. I'll do that.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue, and I found the reason is we run `:PackerUpdate/PackerSync` and packer.vim was removed by itself.

This is my solution:

1. Clone the packer and install it again.

```
git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/wbthomason/packer.nvim\
 ~/.local/share/nvim/site/pack/packer/start/packer.nvim
```

2. Make sure the packer.vim itself is included in startup config block

```
return require('packer').startup(function(use)
    use 'wbthomason/packer.nvim' -- this is essential.
    ...your config...
end)
```

3. Now you can run `:PackerUpdate/PackerSync` in nvim again and everything works fine.

Comment: For the 2.), you mean to add it to ~/.config/nvim/init.lua : https://www.reddit.com/r/neovim/comments/qsysng/comment/hkg3nda/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3

Comment: @MehmetBurakSayıcı that link shows that the answer in the link didn't solve the poster's problem. And neither does the answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by reloading whole nvim.